# HTML based infinite horizontal slider control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, slider

I'm trying to create an infinite slider control. What I mean by infinite is, I want the user to be able to be able to slide on a bar/panel left to right and that will move a date into the past (if they slide left) and into the future (if the slide left). I know there is a few slider controls out there (like http://demos.kendoui.com/web/slider/index.html), but none that I can find that are infinite.

I want a touch friendly graphical based way for the user to move through dates in the ui.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about two buttons:  Increase/Decrease  Forward/Back  Future/Past

Buttons can be clicked an infinite number of times.